# Flash player on Ubuntu 10 not working after Flex builder installation

Tags: apache-flex, flash, ubuntu, flexbuilder

I've just installed Flash builder on my machine, which went ahead and installed the debug version of Flash on my machine as well. It appears now that this has broken Flash in my browsers or at least the browsers have no idea where flash is located on my machine. When I open a browser and navigate to a Flash page I get the message,

"Alternate HTML content should be placed here. This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. Get Flash "

This is from Google chrome but FF is also effected.

How do I fix this to use my installed debug version of flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Debug Flash Player from [Adobe page](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) manually. Seems that you need [this one](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/10/flashplayer_10_plugin_debug.tar.gz).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've tried copying the file to a number of different locations in an attempt to have it picked up by chrome or Firefox but with no success. Eg:

./opt/google/chrome/
./usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/
./home/fergal/.mozilla/plugins/

I still get the '... This content requires the Adobe Flash Player ...' when I navigate to my flash application. Do you know how/where I can configure what flash player is used by my browser?
These symptoms started to appear when I installed Flex Builder so I'm assuming the installer caused this.

Comment: It looks like reinstalling chrome fixes the issue but I'd still like to know how/why it happened.